# When does prolog return fail?

Tags: prolog

Here is my tutor's question.
"In your own words, what possible conclusions can be drawn when prolog returns fail for a query?"

I have never experienced prolog returning fail. I can only assume that it might return fail when an error is encountered through backtracking perhaps?

Comment: are you sure you weren't asked "... returns **false** for a query ?"

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tVzTNd5.png

Answer (score 1):

When Prolog "returns" an indication of failure for a query, it indicates that it failed to prove the query. Example: `2 == 3.`.

---

When you make a query in Prolog, Prolog tries to satisfy it for you. There are two possible outcomes - whether it succeeds, or fails to satisfy the query.

When it succeeds, it indicates the substitutions for a variables in the query, with which it succeeded. If there are several ways to satisfy a query, Prolog will show the substitutions for each of them, if so requested.

If the query succeeds without any substitution to its variables (i.e. there are no variables), the success will be indicated in some way, by printing `Yes`, `true` or whatever, depending on the specific implementation.

Similarly, a failure will be indicated in some way too, e.g. by saying `No`, `false`, or whatever.

(that's *really* basic stuff. You should read some good books on Prolog, or talk to your tutor, a lot. Exercise, exercise, exercise ...) :)